# I want the Jquery thing to show over adsense

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

For example see My site page : http://scansocial.com/22478982

there you can see a jquery thing at topmost and after that adsense. When we click one of Share Tweet Shorturl on Jquery it loads into down which shows adsense in that too

How to make adsense not visible over the Jquery window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the **z-index** on the #panel element and that should fix your problem.

In your stylesheet, just set this property

```
#panel {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

I tried it using Firebug and it worked.

Good luck :)

Comment: Just so that you know, z-index works only for elements that have their position property in CSS set to: fixed, relative, or absolute.